# Python User Input File Name

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, filenames, user-input

I'm trying to write a program that takes a users input for a file name, and then either opens the file to add to it, or prints what is already in the file, so far this is what I have: (I keep getting a syntax error where it tries to print 'file name' is now open) any ideas/tips?

```
            elif choice == 'a':
                print("You selected 'a', you can now add to your file.")
                print("File", ui "is now open.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having the following `print` statement in your `elif` block

```
print("File", ui "is now open.")
```

which is syntactically wrong, since it doesn't have a comma after `ui`, and you can't concatenate or perform any other operation thus.

Either of the following should correct that

```
print("File", ui, "is now open.")
print("File %s is now open." % ui)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another problem beyond the one you asked about:

```
r = open(ui, 'r')
print(r)
close.ui()
```

I assume this is meant to print the contents of the file named by `ui`. But what it will actually do is to print something like `<open file 'filename', mode 'r' at 0x10d7556f0>`, and then throw an exception once it hits `close.ui()`. `r` is the file object; you want to read it, and then close it -- both of these are methods of `r`:

```
r = open(ui, 'r')
print(r.read())
r.close()
```

Hmm, I see you edited this out of your question while I was typing. Hope it helps anyway.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed that did help, I noticed that as well.